# cannot run command on Centos7

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I've got a vps using Centos, the release version is 7.9. I've install the unhide in my vps.it does not work.
I've check the permission, and the file type.
but i still cant run this command . it's always show this error:

```
[root@localhost home]# unhide
-bash: /usr/sbin/unhide: cannot execute binary file

[root@localhost home]# ll /usr/sbin/unhide
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37024 Mar 13  2014 /usr/sbin/unhide
[root@localhost home]# 
[root@localhost home]# 
[root@localhost home]# file /usr/sbin/unhide
/usr/sbin/unhide: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=a094a3e5fbf87ba06c3848f9958e6f694f9b3577, stripped

[root@localhost home]# ldd unhide 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6e17a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f774f38d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f774efbf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f774f5a9000)

[root@localhost home]# uname -m
x86_64
```

the command is runnable. I've test it on another vps.
anyone can explain what happend?

Comment: What is “Unhide”? How exactly did you install it? Do you have a 64-bit Linux installed in your VPS? Check with `uname -m`.

Comment: Can you check your PATH variable ? Use the following command : `echo $PATH`. The path `/usr/sbin` must be in the variable to use directly the `unhide` command

Comment: Run ldd on unhide - see what else it is picking up.   As @DanielB said - run a __uname -m__ to make sure you are not running the i386 version.